# Open URL from file system using PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

In [`page.open`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) I can read about how to open a page using http.

How do use the WebPage module to open an url from the file system?

I have tried to omit `http://` and have an url with `../some_dir/foo.html`, but it seems to fail.

I Have tried this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

fs.changeWorkingDirectory('../foo/bar');

page.open('file://index.html', function(status)
{
    console.log(status);
    //console.log(document.title);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

which outputs "fail".

I got the advice to test an absolute path, trying this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.open('file:///absolute/path/to/index.html', function(status)
{
    console.log(page.title);
    console.log($('body').length);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

(with and without the call to changeWorkingDirectory, but with the same result)

I get a page title, but phantomjs reports that `$` is `undefined`, jQuery is included in my html file (that is too large to post here). It is included like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Trying to run functions also produces errors like

> Can´t find variable: function_name

Comment: Have you trief `file://<path>`? You'll probably need absolute path.

Comment: Trying to use fs.changeWorkingDirectory together with that

Comment: Question updated with a test that outputs "fail".

Comment: Have you tried absolute paths?

Comment: Isnt file://index.html an absolute path?

Comment: If you use unix, then it will be something like `file:///var/www/index.html` or `file:///C:/www/index.html` on windows

Comment: Using "file://C|/projekt/path/index.html" worked, however, $ is not recognized, even if I include jquery

Comment: That's another issue.

Comment: Actually, it does not matter if I make the html invalid, I still get success, so it is never loaded (if I change the filename part to something else than index.html, I get fail as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Does the page/file you are opening already have jquery embedded on the page? If not, you will need to use either injectJs or includeJs on the page object before you can use the `$` operator.

http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html

If you are just doing a simple DOM selection, I would recommend just calling

```
document.querySelector('body').length
```

As these functions already exist within the Phantom instance.

Comment: Yes, I have a script tag, it sais <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>